# Создание error_204

Tags: php, html, html5

Необходимо открытие окна авторизации с помощью ошибки 204 или редиректа 302. В этой теме говорится об этом https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123129/how-does-wifi-in-android-detect-if-the-device-has-to-sign-in-or-not. Но не сказано как это реализовать полностью. Прошу помощи.

Comment: 204 - не ошибка же. Вы имеете ввиду при отсутствии доступа к публичному /generate_204? Тема на которую вы ссылаетесь не о том, как сделать, а о том как сделано.

Comment: Да, это я имел ввиду. Хочется узнать как сделать.